# Php Passing values

Tags: php

I have a problem with this code:

```
    <?php   echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3;search_enroll.php?&id='.$id />"; ?>
```

I'm using this code to pass a value from this page to this page with `$id` and it is not empty I echoed `$id` and it holds the value. And this is the code on the receiving end:

```
   <?php
            if (isset($_POST['SearchS'])){
                $id = $_POST['searchstudent'];

            }else if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
                $id = $_GET['id'];
            }
            else if(!empty($_GET['student_id'])){
                $id = $_GET['student_id'];
            }

            else {
                $id= $_REQUEST['student_id']; <--- this is line 37
            }
            ?>
```

currently having this error note and I expect the 2nd `else` statement should retrieve the code.

```
Notice: Undefined index: student_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Thesis\search_enroll.php on line 37
```

Comment: Your string is messed up, count your quotes. Also, be sure to sanitize any variables before doing anything with them. i.e: addslashes, check if is number, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do your string escaping right or don't do it at all:

```
<?php
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh'
                content='3;search_enroll.php?id=".$id."' />"; ?>
```

Comment: Not a problem, but you should really look into that matter right away. If you learn it wrong, you'll never get the hang of it!

Answer (score 0):

This error appears because of your PHP error reporting settings.

Usually, it appears when your variable is not properly set.

Check if `$_POST['action']` is set before using it.

Answer (score 0):

The meta is not used like that. You hate to specify the URL on a URL subattribute and not just on the CONTENT attribute like that

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="n; URL=MyURL">
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

there, your param is never setted

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@` suppressor in front of a variable when  `Undefined index` error occur.

This error occur when variable is not declared first  and we used in code:

For eg.

```
 else {
     @$id= @$_REQUEST['student_id']; <--- this is line 37
 }
```

But in your case there this else condition should not be run .

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
else {
    if(isset($_REQUEST['student_id'])){
        $id= $_REQUEST['student_id'];
    }
}
```

This will make sure the `student_id` key exists in `$_REQUEST` before you try to access it.

Without a check, it will throw the `Notice`